# How to create a nested dictionary with csv file

Tags: python, mongodb, list, dictionary

I want to create a nested dictionary. From a csv file (see pic) where i want to keep keys same
e.g

```
 {'name':'john' , 'sname':'doe' , 'address':'120 Jefferson st'} ,
 {'name':'jack' , 'sname':'McGinnis', 'address':'202 hobo'}}
```

all the row data in one dictionay with keys as their column name.[image]

stuck here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you want a list of dictionaries.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")

dict_list = []
for i in range (len(data)):
  dict = {}
  for col in data.columns :
    dict[col] = data[col].iloc[i]
  dict_list.append(dict)

print(dict_list)
```

Comment: could you please tell the use of .iloc[i]

Comment: data[col] returns the row at the selected index. Let's say we have 3 columns A, B and C and the first index is A:1, B:2, C:3.

When we call data[1] we get A:1,B:2,C:3.

If we say data[1].iloc[1], it returns the 1st column, which is 1.